# local variable 'user' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, django

I keep getting the error "local variable 'user' referenced before assignment". I'm trying to replicate the user = line of code in this function:

```
def profile_view(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

withing this function, as you can see on on the bottom line:

```
def like_user(request, id):
    pending_like = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    user_like, created = UserLike.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=user.username)
```

however as im not passing through username into the function, so I'm trying to use user.username but i get the error "local variable 'user' referenced before assignment". What is the best way round this? am i do it completely wrong? should i try and pass in username, because when i do i get the error "like_user() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)". Sorry quite new to django, any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: But this doesn't make any sense at all. You haven't got the user yet, so how can you use its username to do the very action of getting it?

Comment: Not to mention, both `pending_like` and `request.user` are both instances of User, so it's not clear why you need to do another query to get another User instance.

Comment: Hi sorry, let me create a new post and ill put the rest of the code in.

Answer (score 0):

Try `request.user.username` instead of `user.username`
It should work

Comment: Hi, the issue is that user is meant to refer to every other user but the request.user, i hope that makes sense

Comment: Even if it did work, this would be *utterly pointless* as it would just get exactly the same instance that you already had as request.user.

Answer (score 0):

```
def profile_view(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

if this is a view function and your intention is to see someone else profile then you have to make changes in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w]+)$', profile_view), 
    # you have to pass the parameter in the url
]
```

otherwise is hard to understand what you want to do